# How to prevent execution of event handler?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wish to authenticate a user each time they click a button.  If the user is logged out, and they attempt to click on a button, they are redirected home.

However the code after `validate()` is executes before the user is redirected home.  In this example the popup always displays before the user is directed back home.  How do I wait for the execution of `validate()` to complete before the rest of the event handler attempts to execute?

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
     validate();
     hello = window.open( '', '', "height = 100, width = 100");
     hello.document.write('hello');
});


function validate(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'validate_user.php',
        dataType: "json",                      
        success: function(response) {            
            if(response.status == 'false') {
                location.href = 'home.php';
            }                
        }       
    });    
}
```

**validate_user.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
        session_destroy();
        $response['status'] = 'false';
    }
    else {
        $response['status'] = 'true';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);          
?>
```

## EDIT

Thanks for the answers, however the popup still displays before the user is directed back even with the code bits of the most upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run your code in the ajax callback instead of directly after you start the request. What the below does is set up your validate function to take a single function parameter. This function is called after the AJAX has been run.

You could even use else on line 14 to only run the code if they are valid users.

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
     validate(function(){
         //some code here
     });

});


function validate(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'validate_user.php',
        dataType: "json",                      
        success: function(response) {            
            if(response.status == 'false') {
                location.href = 'home.php';
            }
            callback();
        }       
    });    
}
```

This is flexible as it allows validate to be used in different contexts.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.5, [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (jQuery's implementation of the promise pattern) as outlined by [jAndy's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9770158/786814) below is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Use a **callback function** at the end of your `success` handler:

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
  validate(function() {
        //code to execute after validate AJAX is complete
  });
});


function validate(cb){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'validate_user.php',
    dataType: "json",                      
    success: function(response) {            
        if(response.status == 'false') {
            location.href = 'home.php';
        } 
        cb();               
    }       
  });    
}
```

This will execute the callback function after the AJAX request is complete, without locking up the UI in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `Deferred` objects, which are encapsulated in each `jqXHR`. Looks like

```
function validate(){
    return $.ajax({   // <-- new return statement
        url: 'validate_user.php',
        dataType: "json",                      
        success: function(response) {            
            if(response.status == 'false') {
                location.href = 'home.php';
            }                
        }       
    });    
}
```

..and after you returning that `jqXHR`, continue like:

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
     validate().done(function() {
         // this code gets executed after the request successfully finished
     });
});
```

This is a very nice and convinient technique to work with asyncronous processes. You can also catch more cases, like `.fail()` for any error case.

Have a further read:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

What about that:

```
$("#main-display").on('click', 'button', function (event){
    validate();
});


function validate(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'validate_user.php',
        dataType: "json",                      
        success: function(response) {            
            if(response.status == 'false') {
                location.href = 'home.php';
            }else{
                //some code here    
            }          
        }       
    });    
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use preventDefault:

```
$("#main-display").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do the rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Synchronous AJAX request dude. By default it will be Asynchronous.

you can do this by adding one parameter..

`async : false`,

Comment: -1. this really is the worst of all solutions, how can this get upvoted?

Comment: check it out documentation of jquery AJAX request dude first n than comment on my answer...
Read this carefully first : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: -1, from the docs: _Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive._

Comment: @PareshBalar: stop trolling please. It totally makes no sense to hang the browser/UI thread from beeing executed here. Thats not how ECMAscript works.